# ¿Cómo unir 2 tablas y filtrar una de ellas por el último registro ingresado de cada identificador?

Tags: sql

estoy teniendo problemas con una consulta de SQL, tengo una tabla A, que lleva el historico de la table B, tiene exactamente los mismos campos, necesito sacar el último dato insertado, la tabla historica, tiene un campo Fecha_Insert, entonces un ID 2 puede tener varios registros en el historico, pero el que me interesa es el último insertado. Esto con el objetivo de comparar un 3er campo llamado forma_de_pago que se encuentra en ambas tablas. He estado probando esto:

```
SELECT a.* FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(FECHA_INSERT), forma_de_pago
FROM B where CATEGORIA = 'AC' GROUP BY ID) AS b ON (a.ID = b.ID)
WHERE a.forma_de_pago = b.forma_de_pago
```

pero me da el error:

> COLUMN A.forma_de_pago is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

entonces no puedo realizar la comparación.

Alguien sabe ¿cuál puede ser el problema? entiendo que la columna no lleva una función agregada como el max, pero es porque no la necesito.

Gracias.

Comment: Si `forma_de_pago` no la necesitas, quitala del `select`, y si la necesitas, agregala al `group by`

Comment: Gracias Patricio, en efecto eso era lo que me faltaba.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
Select * from (
Select ID, MAX(FECHA_INSERT) from b) b,
(SELECT ID, MAX(FECHA_INSERT) from A) a
Where b.id=a.id
```

Si comentas que los datos en las dos tablas son iguales deberias servirte....

Saludos